# Bonjour programming for java?

Tags: java, iphone, objective-c, networking

I wanted to communicate with a java server running the computer using iPhone. I did some research and found bonjour programming..it sounds all good but I am looking for a tutorial which shows how to impliment in java..

thanks

**if  there are any alternatives to bonjour please let me know**

Comment: You cannot write in Java on the iPhone. It's limited to Objective-C/Cocoa. Using that, there are several ways of communicating with a server, but you'll have to say more about what your goals are.

Comment: sorry for not making it clear..I would like to write a server in java which runs on the computer....so in other words would like this server to communicate with iphone application using bonjour....sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Google says [try this](https://wiki.cs.columbia.edu:8443/display/res/JBonjourBrowser).  It is GPL but you can read it! :)

I assume you already have your Apple Developer id.  Apple maintains *superb* documentation on Mac OS X.  I'd look for Bonjour Java Library. (All assuming you are open to a Mac OS X Server)